PLACEHOLDER - My Stack Overflow Automation
My Stack Overflow Automation
Description
This application automates the process of saving posts as favorites on Stack Overflow.
Features

Automatically saves specified Stack Overflow posts as favorites.
Uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication.

Usage

Authorize the application using OAuth.
Use the provided scripts to favorite posts by their IDs.

How to Obtain OAuth Tokens

Visit the authorization URL: https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=29046&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback
Authorize the application and get the authorization code.
Exchange the authorization code for an access token.

Example Scripts

Script to get access token.
Script to favorite posts using the access token.

